# How to get the i'th element of an associative array?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have the array:

```
array(2=>'0',3=>'1',5=>'3',4=>'4',7=>'2')
```

**Note:** Nothing seems to be in order. So leave the plan to find a numeric order.

How can I fixed the i'th element of this associative array?

For example when `i` is `4` the value should be `4`,
when `i` is `1` the value should be `0`.

`array_shift()` never solves this requirement. Knowing very well that the logic of looping solves this problem.

Comment: Show your attempt and where you are stuck

Comment: array_XXX a function between j and l

Comment: @Rizier123 Let me ask you a simple question, for eg. how can you make an attempt when the solution is `a[i]`?

Comment: @AtaboyDaniel I think you are stuck with: `a[i]`, you can't get it that simple to work. But you can get close to this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work for you:

Here you just can use [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) to access the keys of your associative array as a numerical indexed array, which you then again can use as key for the array.

```
$arr = array(2=>'0',3=>'1',5=>'3',4=>'4',7=>'2');
echo $arr[array_keys($arr)[3]];
                         //^ This is your 'i'
```

output:

```
4
```

*when the solution is a[i]* <- You can't get it that simple, but you get close with the solution above. (Note, that since the array with the keys is 0-based index, the 4th element is index 3)

You can use a variable and then subtract one, to get your logic, that 4 => 4.

```
$i = 4;
$arr = array(2=>'0',3=>'1',5=>'3',4=>'4',7=>'2');
echo $arr[array_keys($arr)[$i-1]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Without function call, maybe, faster

```
$arr = array(2=>'0',3=>'1',5=>'3',4=>'4',7=>'2');
$i = 4;
foreach($arr as $v) 
   if(!--$i) { echo $v; break; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$arr1 = array(2=>'0',3=>'1',5=>'3',4=>'4',7=>'2');
$i=0;
$findIndex = 4;
$value = '';
foreach($arr1 AS $ele) {
    if ($findIndex == $i) {
        $value = $ele;
        break;
    }
    $i++;
}
echo $value ? $value : 'Not found';
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.